# Passing a hostname of over 255 characters to getaddrinfo causes a getaddrinfo failed: memory allocation failure why?

Tags: c, unix, network-programming, ipv6

I am currently upgrading our software to support ipv6 and in the meantime I'm expanding hostname/ip fields to the max hostname size. In sun documentation it seems like this can be up to 1025 (netdb.h:#define NI_MAXHOST 1025 - this is the recommended hostname allocation define), but when I pass a hostname of over 255 to getaddrinfo I get "getaddrinfo failed: memory allocation failure". I am testing on a Sol10 box. Ideas?

Comment: can you show the code where you are getting the error?

Comment: does it work with smaller hostnames?

Comment: Looks like a general Sol10 limit, hostnames are restricted short too,  http://chihungchan.blogspot.com/2008/01/hostname-maximum-length-in-solaris.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NI_MAXHOST is for getnameinfo(), getaddrinfo() uses the MAXHOSTNAMELEN. (see [here](http://src.opensolaris.org/source/xref/onnv/onnv-gate/usr/src/lib/libsocket/inet/getaddrinfo.c)) , and that seems pretty much to be hardcoded - and there's little you can do about it.

Exactly why these differ I don't know, but see e.g. also [here](http://www.ops.ietf.org/lists/namedroppers/namedroppers.2003/msg00969.html)/[here](http://www.ops.ietf.org/lists/namedroppers/namedroppers.2003/msg00964.html) for some info on max host name lengths.

Answer (score 0):

You have no choice: this limit of 255 characters is the standard. Let me quote [RFC 1123](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1123.txt), section 2.1:

> Host software MUST handle host names of up to 63 characters and
>   SHOULD handle host names of up to 255 characters.